# Refresh and Delete Marker on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google Maps functions and i want to know on how to delete markers on Map , Will refreshing the map removes the Marker or do I need to Add something to Remove the markers ??

I am adding marker by using Getjson loop from database. .

Here is my set of codes

```
var Rad = 0;
var customerlocationID = 0;

var geocoder, infoBubble, geocode;
var map;
var selectedMarker;
var ID;
//var mgr;
$("#ddlRadius").live("change", function () {
    var selectValue = "";
    selectValue = $("#ddlRadius option:selected").val();

    if (selectValue == "77") {
        Rad = 5;
        codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad);
    } else if (selectValue == "78") {
        Rad = 10;
        codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad);
    } else if (selectValue == "79") {
        Rad = 25;
        codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad);
    } else if (selectValue == "80") {
        Rad = 50;
        codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad);
    } else if (selectValue == "81") {
        Rad = 100;
        codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad);
    }
});


function initialize() {
    var minZoomLevel = 4;
    var zooms = 7;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocode = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    // Used to Set the Center of the Maps on the Logged User
    $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadAddress', function Geocoding(address) {
        $.each(address, function () {
            customerlocationID = this["ID"];
            var currValAddress = this["AddressLine1"];
            var Latitude = this["Latitude"];
            var Longitude = this["Longitude"];
            var LatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
            var addresse = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: LatLang,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), addresse);


            // Bounds for North America
            var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
            new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90));

            // Listen for the dragend event
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
                if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;
                // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

                var c = map.getCenter(),
                    x = c.lng(),
                    y = c.lat(),
                    maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
                    maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
                    minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
                    minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

                if (x < minX) x = minX;
                if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
                if (y < minY) y = minY;
                if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
            });

            // Limit the zoom level
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
                if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
            });
        });
    });
    codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad);
}

var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';

function codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad) {
    infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
        map: map,
        shadowStyle: 0,
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        arrowSize: 15,
        maxWidth: 300,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ccc',
        arrowPosition: 50,
        arrowStyle: 0
    });
    $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList1' + '?customerLocationID=' + customerlocationID + '&radius=' + Rad, function Geocode(addresses) {
        $.each(addresses, function () {
            var currVal = this["AddressLine1"];
            var Name = this["Name"];
            var Gender = this["Gender"];
            var Bdate = this["Birthdate"];
            ID = this["Worker_ID"];
            var distance = this["Distance"];
            var workerDetailIDDD = this["Worker_ID"];
            var Latitude = this["Latitude"];
            var Longitude = this["Longitude"];
            var LatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: '/Content/images/male.png',
                position: LatLang,
                title: currVal
            })

            var link = $('<a href="#">' + currVal + '</a>').data('location', LatLang);
            $('#places').append($('<li id=\'List\' class=\'List\'>').append(link));
            link.on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                google.maps.event.trigger(addresses[0], "click");
                if (selectedMarker) {
                    selectedMarker.setIcon('/Content/images/male.png');
                }
                marker.setIcon('/Content/images/maleclicked.png');
                selectedMarker = marker;
                infoBubble.removeTab(0);
                infoBubble.addTab(Name, "Name: " + Name + "<br> Address: " + currVal + "<br> Gender: " + Gender + "<br> Birthdate: " + Bdate + "<br> Distance: " + distance + "<br><br>" + '<center><a href="/Dashboard/WorkerMapDetail?workerId=' + workerDetailIDDD + '" onclick="window.open(this.href,height=850,width=1200);return false""><span style="font-size: 12px !important">View Profile</span></a></center>');
                infoBubble.open(map, marker);
            });


            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
                $('#places li').each(function () {
                    var inside = (map.getBounds().contains($(this).find('a').data('location'))) ? '' : 'none';
                    $(this).css('display', inside);
                });
            });

            // Listen for user click on map to close any open info bubbles
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function () {
                infoBubble.close();
                marker.setIcon('/Content/images/male.png');
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragstart", function () {
                infoBubble.close();
                marker.setIcon('/Content/images/male.png');
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    if (selectedMarker) {
                        selectedMarker.setIcon('/Content/images/male.png');
                    }
                    marker.setIcon('/Content/images/maleclicked.png');
                    selectedMarker = marker;
                    infoBubble.removeTab(0);
                    infoBubble.addTab(Name, "Name: " + Name + "<br> Address: " + currVal + "<br> Gender: " + Gender + "<br> Birthdate: " + Bdate + "<br> Distance: " + distance + "<br><br>" + '<center><a href="/Dashboard/WorkerMapDetail?workerId=' + workerDetailIDDD + '" onclick="window.open(this.href,height=850,width=1200);return false""><span style="font-size: 12px !important">View Profile</span></a></center>');
                    infoBubble.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, currVal));
        })
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'bounds_changed');
    })
}
window.onload = function () {
    initialize();
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove a marker from a map by passing `null` to the marker's `.setMap()` function, like this:

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

If you want to remove all the markers from a map, you must keep an array of the markers and call `.setMap(null)` on all of them, like this:

```
$.each(markers, function() {
    this.setMap(null);
});
```

Comment: so i can remove all the marker then add new ones with `this.setMap(null);` ??

Comment: because the problem is that everytime i changes drop down value the marker duplicates